# Passing image from js button in browser to Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow.js

I have an image classifier that takes in images from the user and passes it to Tensorflow.js, but I can't seem to get the image loaded and passed to tf.browser.fromPixels.

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm not sure I'm implementing FileReader correctly.

```
<body>
  <input id="image-selector" type="file">
  <button id="predict-button">Predict</button>
  <img id="selected-image" src=""/>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("predict-button").onclick = async function() {run()};
  async function run() {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let dataURL = reader.result;
  document.getElementById("selected-image").src=dataURL;
  const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(selected-image);
  const resized_image = tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [300,300]).toFloat();
  const batchedImage = resized_image.expandDims(0);
  const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/model.json';
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  const result = model.predict(batchedImage);
  result.print();

}

</script>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are facing?

Comment: On clicking on the button predict, do you want to select a file ?